# Retain undo buffer after quitting VIM?

Tags: vim

I'm wondering if it is possible to retain VIM's undo buffer after quitting.

For example, I'd like to make some edits to a file, save & quit (:wq), then reopen the file and still be able to hit 'u' to undo the edits.  Is this possible in VIM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That isn't currently possible.  There is an item in the [TODO list](http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/doc/todo.txt) and there was a [proposed patch](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/22829) on the development mailing list, though.

---

**Updated 2010/6/6**: The pre-release work on Vim 7.3 has included the persistent undo patch.

Comment: Ah, much thanks for the speedy reply.  Keeping fingers crossed for inclusion of this patch in the future.  Cheers...

Answer (score 4):

You probably already know it, but in most cases you can just save, then Ctrl-Z to go to the shell, and then fg to return to vim.